# Relational Grammar arcs

Tags: diagrams, syntax, linguistics

I'm quite used to draw syntactic trees and even AVMs for different linguistic theories, but I've stumbled upon the need to draw Relational Grammar / Arc-paired grammar arcs for a paper I'm writing (search for "relational grammar" in Google Images to have a glimpse on how these arcs look like). Does anybody of a package that may be useful for this?

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to browse through [http://www.ctan.org/topic/linguistic] for available linguistic packages.

Comment: As far as I know there is no package for drawing RG structures. It's not that hard to cook them up individually with TikZ, but creating a more general method would require quite a bit of work, I suspect. How many diagrams would you be drawing and how complex would they get?

Comment: @nvteighen Would you mind providing a link to something that shows what you want? I could help you better that way!

Answer (score 7):

The following example shows how you could draw one of these diagrams by hand using TikZ. It's not clear to me what a reasonable syntax might be for automating this; I don't work in the RG framework so I don't know what would make sense.  Making more complex diagrams for clause union or clause reduction structures would also likely need to be done by hand.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,intersections,matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
stratum/.style={red, shorten <=-10pt,shorten >=-10pt},
arc/.style={-latex}
]
\coordinate (root);
\matrix (S) [below=3cm of root,matrix of nodes]
{
eat & woman & apple\\
};
\draw [arc,name path=Pred]  (root)  to [bend right=40] 
   coordinate [pos=.5] (P) coordinate [pos=.75] (P2) (S-1-1) ;
\draw [arc,name path=Two]  (root)  to [bend left=10] (S-1-2) ;
\draw [arc,name path=One] (root)  to [bend left=50] 
   coordinate [pos=.5] (2) coordinate [pos=.75] (1) (S-1-3) ;
\draw[stratum,name path=Stratum1] (P) to  [bend left=20] (2);
\draw[stratum,name path=Stratum2] (P2) to  [bend left=20] (1);
\fill [name intersections={of=Stratum1 and Pred,by={[label=above left:P]}}];
\fill [name intersections={of=Stratum1 and One,by={[label=above right:2]}}];
\fill [name intersections={of=Stratum1 and Two,by={[label=above left:1]}}];
\fill [name intersections={of=Stratum2 and Pred,by={[label=above left:P]}}];
\fill [name intersections={of=Stratum2 and One,by={[label=above right:1]}}];
\fill [name intersections={of=Stratum2 and Two,by={[label=above left:Cho]}}];
\end{tikzpicture}

``The apple was eaten by the woman.''
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]